# Hook_form_FORM_ID_alter to alter views exposed form

Tags: views, forms, hooks

I am attempting to create a function which will alter the exposed form of a view in order to display a certain image instead of the button which says 'Apply'. I have the code below and I could use some help in debunking why it doesn't work.

```
function ana_zymphonies_form_views-exposed-form-search-content-page-1_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
$form['submit'] = [
'#type' => 'image_button', 
'#src' => base_path() . path_to_theme() . '/images/search.png'
];
}
```

Comment: The function name is invalid

Comment: To expand on that - needs underscores, not hyphens. The function name you've written will not be picked up.

Comment: Thank you, the site is loading but the function still doesn't work xd

Comment: Clear your site cache whenever you implement a new hook.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! You should also say what isn't working. A phrase like _it doesn't work_ doesn't help in understanding what you obtain and in which way that is different from what you expect.